# QuickSorting By Name using Recursion c#

Tags: c#, string, sorting, recursion, sharp

This is a homework project.

My goal is to sort my list of animals in alphabetical order by name by implementing a quick sort using recursion.
I've accomplished this successfully with my animals weights as demonstrated below with a snippet of the code and my results that are associated with it.

```
public static SortResult QuickSortByWeight(List<Animal> animals, int leftIndex, int rightIndex, SortResult sortResult)
    {
            // define variables to keep track of the left and right points in the list
            // initialize them to the passed-in indexes
            int leftPointer = leftIndex;
            int rightPointer = rightIndex;

            // find the animal to pivot on (the middle animal in this case)
            Animal pivotAnimal = animals[(leftIndex + rightIndex) / 2];

            // define and initialize a loop variable
            bool done = false;

            // start looping
            while (!done)
            {
                // while the weight of the animal at the left pointer spot in the list is less than the pivot animal's weight
                while (animals[leftPointer].Weight < pivotAnimal.Weight)
                {
                    // increment the left pointer
                    leftPointer++;
                    // increment the sort result's compare count
                    sortResult.CompareCount++;
                }

                // while the pivot animal's weight is less than the weight of the animal at the right pointer spot in the list
                while (pivotAnimal.Weight < animals[rightPointer].Weight)
                {
                    // decrement the right pointer
                    rightPointer--;
                    // increment the sort result's compare count
                    sortResult.CompareCount++;
                }

                // if the left pointer is less than or equal to the right pointer
                if (leftPointer <= rightPointer)
                {
                    // swap the animals at the left pointer and right pointer spots
                    SortHelper.Swap(animals, leftPointer, rightPointer);
                    // increment the sort result's swap count
                    sortResult.SwapCount++;
                    // then increment the left pointer and decrement the right pointer
                    leftPointer++;
                    rightPointer--;
                }

                // if the left pointer is greater than the right pointer,
                // stop the outer while loop
                if (leftPointer > rightPointer)
                {
                    done = true;
                }
            }

        // if the left index is less than the right pointer
        // use recursion to sort the animals within the left index and right pointer
        if (leftIndex < rightPointer)
        {
            // method call here
            QuickSortByWeight(animals, leftIndex, rightPointer, sortResult);
        }

        //// if the left pointer is less than the right index
        //// use recursion to sort the animals within the left pointer and right index
        if (leftPointer < rightIndex)
        {
            // method call here
            QuickSortByWeight(animals, leftPointer, rightIndex, sortResult);
        }

        sortResult.Animals = animals;

        return new SortResult { SwapCount = sortResult.SwapCount, CompareCount = sortResult.CompareCount, ElapsedMilliseconds = sortResult.ElapsedMilliseconds, Animals = animals };
    }
```

[image: Sorting By Weight]

I thought when quickSorting by name I could use .CompareTo with my current animals name along with the same logic behind sorting by weight, however I've been unsuccessful in doing so with a IndexOutOfRange exception using the following code:

```
 public static SortResult QuickSortByName(List<Animal> animals, int leftIndex, int rightIndex, SortResult sortResult)
    {
        // define variables to keep track of the left and right points in the list
        // initialize them to the passed-in indexes
        int leftPointer = leftIndex;
        int rightPointer = rightIndex;

        // find the animal to pivot on (the middle animal in this case)
        Animal pivotAnimal = animals[(leftIndex + rightIndex) / 2];

        // define and initialize a loop variable
        bool done = false;

        // start looping
        while (!done)
        {
            // while the name of the animal at the left pointer spot in the list is less than the pivot animal's name
            while (animals[leftPointer].Name.CompareTo(pivotAnimal.Name) < leftPointer)
            {
                // increment the left pointer
                leftPointer++;
                // increment the sort result's compare count
                sortResult.CompareCount++;
            }

            // while the pivot animal's name is less than the name of the animal at the right pointer spot in the list
            while (pivotAnimal.Name.CompareTo(animals[rightPointer].Name) < rightPointer)
            {
                // decrement the right pointer
                rightPointer--;
                // increment the sort result's compare count
                sortResult.CompareCount++;
            }

            // if the left pointer is less than or equal to the right pointer
            if (leftPointer <= rightPointer)
            {
                // swap the animals at the left pointer and right pointer spots
                SortHelper.Swap(animals, leftPointer, rightPointer);
                // increment the sort result's swap count
                sortResult.SwapCount++;
                // then increment the left pointer and decrement the right pointer
                leftPointer++;
                rightPointer--;
            }

            // if the left pointer is greater than the right pointer,
            // stop the outer while loop
            if (leftPointer > rightPointer)
            {
                done = true;
            }
        }

        // if the left index is less than the right pointer
        // use recursion to sort the animals within the left index and right pointer
        if (leftIndex < rightPointer)
        {
            // method call here
            QuickSortByName(animals, leftIndex, rightPointer, sortResult);
        }

        //// if the left pointer is less than the right index
        //// use recursion to sort the animals within the left pointer and right index
        if (leftPointer < rightIndex)
        {
            // method call here
            QuickSortByName(animals, leftPointer, rightIndex, sortResult);
        }

        sortResult.Animals = animals;

        return new SortResult { SwapCount = sortResult.SwapCount, CompareCount = sortResult.CompareCount, ElapsedMilliseconds = sortResult.ElapsedMilliseconds, Animals = animals };
    }
```

If I can come out of this discussion understanding why my syntax is wrong for sorting by name I'm thankful for the insight.

Comment: You must not compare the result of the `String.CompareTo()` method to your `leftPointer` or `rightPointer`. Compare the result with `< 0`. `CompareTo` returns a negative value if the instance precedes the argument.

Comment: Changing the compare result to < 0 worked, thank you G Wimpassinger.  Such a small fix that had quite the impact.  I'll have to keep this example in mind for the future.